# DB::table Select() returns Array as String Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I want to get users list as per distance and in user DB I stored user images in json format. When I use `DB::table` it return as string not as array.

Please Help me.

My Controller:

```
$doc = DB::table( 'users' )
            ->select(
                'id',
                'name',
                'image',
                'latitude',
                'longitude' )
            ->selectRaw( "{$getDistance} AS distance" )
            ->orderBy( 'distance' )
            ->get();
```

CURRENT JSON RESPONSE:

```
{
"name": "User One",
"image": "[\"f0f159c7238b8c9a1a3e5c9bd48de2a5cJ8Y4ssqzcuoWJAS1614581337EC2fGzmRCjf9wphI.webp\", 
         \"f0f159c7238b8c9a1a3e5c9bd48de2a5tvof9EarZgvupGpa1614581337zvPSnQchCjSL9lZS.webp\"]",
}
```

What I WANT TO GET:

```
{
"name": "User One",
"image": ["f0f159c7238b8c9a1a3e5c9bd48de2a5cJ8Y4ssqzcuoWJAS1614581337EC2fGzmRCjf9wphI.webp", 
         "f0f159c7238b8c9a1a3e5c9bd48de2a5tvof9EarZgvupGpa1614581337zvPSnQchCjSL9lZS.webp"],
}
```

Comment: how do you return your json in controller?

Comment: maybe it is because of distance, you just do this $doc = DB::table( 'users' )
            ->select(
                'id',
                'name',
                'image',
                'latitude',
                'longitude' )          
            ->get();and check what you get

Comment: Why not use Eloquent ORM Query?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jsonencode or jsondecode before send the response.

i would use `$doc->image = json_encode($doc->image());`

and then

```
return response()->json('data' => $doc);
```